# Image alignment and size in Redactor 2

Tags: redactor, richtext, image

Redactor I had a feature that allowed editing of image alignment (via the image popup) and size (by dragging the square bounding box), is it possible to enable this functionality in Redactor II?

Is this something that can be done with `formattingAdd`?

[image: example of Redactor 1 image editing controls]

Answer (score 12):

No need for a plugin.
Just add:

```
 "imageResizable": true,
 "imagePosition": true,
```

to your chosen redactor config file i.e. (/craft/config/redactor/standard.json)

Answer (score 0):

Redactor 2 removed a lot of functionality and delegated to plugins, including the functionality you're after. It made Redactor more lightweight but more of a hassle to get functionality back in, especially when using Craft CMS, where a plugin is required.

This plugin should provide you with the image position functionality:
https://github.com/picdorsey/craft-redactorimageposition

I have not yet seen a plugin for the image size functionality, although it should be straightforward to create. Good luck!!